# Does food grade diatomaceous earth contain mercury

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, homework

Not sure if this is the right site to ask this question, but since diatomes are or once were biological creatures it seemed to fit this one more than any of the others. I have been supplementing my food, and my cats food occasionally, with food grade diatomaceous earth which is supposed to be healthy and good for bones, teath, skin, hair and cell growth among other things, it is inhert & has no known side effects, its is used regularly as a cattle feed additive & also as a pesticide or anti-parasite treatment to kill worms, fluke and other critters.. I only started doing this as a supplement as i do not generally eat alot of vegtables or fruit & am more of a snacking person.. However I just seen an article that say's beer, wine and many other beverages contain mercury as many of them are filtered using diatomaceous earth (Which pressumably would have to be Food Grade). If there are any minerologist/biologist's is this true? Where does the mercury come from? is it safe? Can the human body filter this out?

Comment: That's an earth sciences question or a food forum question. google will research better than we can. first result http://www.vitaletherapeutics.org/deanlsbw.htm

Comment: You are more likely to find mercury in natural gas ( before the gas plant filters it out).

Comment: Thank you for the reference com.prehensible, thats exactly what i was looking for. if this question is not suited here please can someone migrate it to earth science or similar...